# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: in groovy

Tags: groovy

I am new to groovy code. I have a map like this

```
response = {"data":{"--class":"java.util.HashMap","Enabled":false,"Adult":"[recursive reference removed]","TVMA":"[recursive reference removed]","Locks":[false,false,false,false,false,false],"PINEnabled":false,"AdvisoryLocks":[false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false],"safeSearch":"[recursive reference removed]","RatingLocks":[false,false,false,false,false,false]},"success":true}
```

Using groovy code I want to check the presence of the following keys:

```
Enabled,
Adult,
TVMA,
Locks,
PINEnabled,
AdvisoryLocks,
safeSearch,
RatingLocks,
```

I am using the following code:

```
 for ( data in response.data ) {
            println("-----------------------------------------")       

            assertNotNull(data.Enabled)
            assertNotNull(data.Adult)
            ;;;;;;
            .......
            }
        Am getting groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Enabled
```

How can I check the presence of the above keys from response map using groovy?

Comment: That's not a map.  Do you have a reproducible example of `response`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can find keys value from the Json like below.

```
       def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
       def result = slurper.parseText(response)
       assert result.data.Enabled != null
       assert result.data.Enabled != ""
       assert result.data.Adult != null
       assert result.data.Adult != ""
```

I hope that will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using good'ol regexp?

```
String response = '{"data":{"--class":"java.util.HashMap","Enabled":false,"Adult":"[recursive reference removed]","TVMA":"[recursive reference removed]","Locks":[false,false,false,false,false,false],"PINEnabled":false,"AdvisoryLocks":[false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false],"safeSearch":"[recursive reference removed]","RatingLocks":[false,false,false,false,false,false]},"success":true}'
assert [ 'Enabled', 'Adult', 'TVMA',,,, ].every{ response =~ /"$it":/ }
```